# Logs are filling up with httpclient.wire.content dumps. How can I turn it off?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, apache-commons-httpclient

My catalina logs are filling up with gobs of statements like:

```
/logs/catalina.out:2010-05-05 02:57:19,611 [Thread-19] DEBUG httpclient.wire.content - >> "[0x4]
[0xc][0xd9][0xf4][0xa2]MA[0xed][0xc2][0x93][0x1b][0x15][0xfe],[0xe]h[0xb0][0x1f][0xff][0xd6][0xfb]
[0x8f]O[0xd4][0xc4]0[0xab][0x80][0xe8][0xe4][0xf2][\r]I&[0xaa][0xd2]BQ[0xdb](zq[0xcd]ac[0xa8]
```

on and on forever.

I searched every config file in both tomcat and apache for the statements that purportedly turn this on as described here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html

And I don't see where this logging has been enabled. No other .war I deployed does this. The log4j configuration block in the app isn't doing it.

I also tried to turn it off with statements like this:

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.wire=SEVERE
```

or

```
org.apache.commons.httpclient.wire.content=SEVERE
```

or

```
httpclient.wire.content=SEVERE
```

in my tomcat/conf/logging.properties file, and that didn't stop it

I'm using an S3 library for grails that may be the source for these. However when I run this application on my development machine (in both develop and deploy configs), I'm not seeing it.

And a related question: When would I want to use these "wire logs?"

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have any additional logging library in your Tomcat common/lib? (i.e SLF4J, Logback, Log4J, etc)

If yes, you may want to configure the respective logging configuration file as well.

Comment: Thanks! I fixed it with a line in the log4j section in my config.groovy. (Though I'm not sure which line did it: to be safe I tried: 
      'httpclient.wire.content',
      'org.apache.commons.httpclient.wire.content'

Now I have to back them out one at a time to see which one is the correct syntax!

Comment: @user122299 can you please explain a bit more. did you figure out the correct line.

Answer (score 8):

For Slf4J:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- LOGGING -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9-RC0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9-RC0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And put logback.xml in your classpath with the content below:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- LOGBACK logging config file, see http://logback.qos.ch/manual/joran.html -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <!-- http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout -->
            <Pattern>%-5level %msg [%logger{16} %d{HH:mm:ss}]%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.axis2" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="org.apache.axiom" level="WARN" />
    <logger name="httpclient.wire" level="WARN" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: This works well. However, be sure to update the assembly version references listed in the example pom.xml. For example, this is currently the latest entry for: logback-classic: 
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic 

<dependency>
    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer for Tomcat 8.5.1 - currently solved the issue on Centos. Like many, I wasted quite a bit of time on this.   the httpclient has built in logging so you can't fix it with log4j or slf4j- and the answer is provided here. 
This applies if no other logging systems are included.

[http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html][1]

Create a logging.properties file and place in /src/main/resources - so that it is deployed to WEB-INF/classes (the example changes the default FINE to WARN

Example logging.properties for the servlet-examples web application to be placed in WEB-INF/classes inside the web application:

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = WARNING
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = ${classloader.webappName}.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = WARNING
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.OneLineFormatter
```