# apache httpclient logs passwords in cleartext when debug logging is turned on

Tags: java, apache, httpclient

Apache httpclient seems to log passwords in cleartext when debug logging is turned on.

Is there a way to disable this?  So that I can see the rest of the debug logging but not the credentials?

Comment: HttpClient logs everything passing over the network and through it. It does not know what is a password and what is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a SHA1 hash of the password in memory before you send it on the network.

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
byte[] sha1hash = new byte[40];
md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, text.length()); // TODO verify the lengths are the same
sha1hash = md.digest();
```

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-sha-hashing-example/

If you absolutely need cleartext passwords, you have several choices:

1. You can disable logging for the headers or set it to a level higher than debug: [Disable HttpClient logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)
2. You can dynamically disable the logging right before you send the password and then turn it back on again: [Dynamically configuring Apache Http client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557178/dynamically-configuring-apache-http-client)
3. You can implement your own Logger handler/formatter or subclass one of the basic ones and search the output for your password and replace it with `XXXXXXXXX`. Then set the handler to your class: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

Comment: What if the requested page requires the plain password?

Answer (score 0):

In log4j.properties set

`log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.level=WARN`

Comment: What if people want to debug? Should they never do it?