# How to disable debug messages in gradle

Tags: logging, gradle

I am currently using gradle to build some spring project. But when I run the project, a lot of debug messages appear. How should I disable these debug messages in the gradle configuration file?

Something like:

```
12:58:40.149 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match 12:58:40.157 
[main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "run" the project. Are these messages output by your running application or by the Gradle build itself. Can you post an example of these messages?

Comment: It seems that messages come from the application itself.

Comment: Something like: 12:58:40.149 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAddCookies - CookieSpec selected: best-match
12:58:40.157 [main] DEBUG o.a.h.c.protocol.RequestAuthCache - Auth cache not set in the context

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments the logging output comes not from gradle but rather the application more specifically HttpClient.

By default [gradle logging](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/logging.html) is set to `LIFECYCLE` or higher, not `DEBUG`.

It seems that http client is indeed a bit noisy when it comes to logging. [Disable HttpClient logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)

Considering that you are using Spring , you might want to set the logging specifics in you [logging configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging) for Spring. I like using slf4j which uses so-called bridges that gather logging messages from other logging frameworks and outputs them to one configured logger implementation like logback.