# Hide third party jar logs from logback or properties file

Tags: java, spring, logging, slf4j

I am using Third Party jars which are appending their own logs in my Java Application's Log file , I don't want to append those third party logs in my log file as it makes log file very clumsy and confusing.

The logs are like -

```
`2016-11-03 12:59:41.910 ERROR 13586 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.metamodel.MetadataContext        : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : org.openskye.domain.TaskQueue_#object_metadata_id
2016-11-03 12:59:41.913 ERROR 13586 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.metamodel.MetadataContext        : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : org.openskye.domain.TaskQueue_#id
2016-11-03 12:59:41.914 ERROR 13586 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.metamodel.MetadataContext        : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : org.openskye.domain.TaskQueue_#status
2016-11-03 12:59:41.914 ERROR 13586 --- [           main] o.h.j.i.metamodel.MetadataContext        : HHH015011: Unable to locate static metamodel field : org.openskye.domain.TaskQueue_#path
```

For hide the logs for the package available in my application I use

> logging.level.package-name= INFO

but this is not work for the third party jar. Please help me

`

Comment: Try telling those packages to set their logging level to OFF (level="off").

Comment: Similarly we faced the httpclient logging issue once. You can find the related answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging#answer-5432242

Answer (score 1):

You can set the rootLogger level to OFF and than set the logLevel for your base package to what ever you want, 
this leads to logging only for your classes.