# Exclude from logs in Java - DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire

Tags: java, spring, docker, testcontainers

Have a Spring Boot project and while running integration tests I get plenty of these debug messages. Which library is generating them and how to exclude them properly?

```
13:41:03.966 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "accept: application/json[\r][\n]"                                                              
13:41:03.966 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "x-tc-sid: 0c130805-5b48-4da1-acf4-45a0a4833e0f[\r][\n]
13:41:03.966 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "User-Agent: tc-java/1.19.0[\r][\n]"
13:41:03.966 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]
13:41:03.967 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Host: localhost:2375[\r][\n]                                                                                       
13:41:03.967 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]                                                                                     
13:41:03.967 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 >> "[\r][\n]"                                                                                                          
13:41:03.969 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]                                                                                            
13:41:03.969 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Api-Version: 1.41[\r][\n]                                                                                          
13:41:03.969 [ducttape-1] DEBUG com.github.dockerjava.zerodep.shaded.org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire - http-outgoing-3 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
```

Tried adding to the application.yml file:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.hibernate: WARN
    com.github: WARN
    org.apache.http: WARN
    org.testcontainers: WARN
    org.postgresql: WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it. It is org.rnotrth.ducttape library. To exclude its debug messages from logs just use:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.rnorth: WARN
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines come from `HttpClient`. Here is the discussion on how to turn it off:
[Disable HttpClient logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)

In my case helped adding logback.xml file with the following content:

```
<configuration debug="false">
    <!-- definition of appender STDOUT -->
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <!-- appender referenced after it is defined -->
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```