# Set apache HttpClient log level explicitly

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am developing a web application which among the other uses the apache HttpClient to make some httpRequest.
For logging I am using slf4j with the slf4j-log4j12 'plug in'

What I want is to have DEBUG log level for my application but WARN level for the HttpClient. I am seeting the logging properties in `log4j.properties`.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout   
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender   
log4j.appender.file.File=log.log   
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG
```

The initialization and logging is like that

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
private static final org.slf4j.Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(<MY_CLASS>.class.getName());

LOG.debug("This is debug info");
LOG.warn("This is warn info");
```

Until now I am setting the following to the class that uses HttpClient

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
```

In order to 'deactivate' logging, but this stops the logging completely and does not set the level to WARN as I want.

Until now I have tried what is proposed on the following SO questions but with no luck. I have also seen many other which suggest pretty much the same.

- [Disable HttpClient logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging)
- [Logs are filling up with httpclient.wire.content dumps. How can I turn it off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770382/logs-are-filling-up-with-httpclient-wire-content-dumps-how-can-i-turn-it-off)

Passing parameters on execution such as `java -Dlog4j` is not a solution for me.

As a sidenote my project has two modules,

- The 'parent module' defines the logging properties and has the slf4j (1.7.5) and slf4j-log4j12 dependencies
- The child module is where I am using the HttpClient (4.3.4), it has only the
  slf4j (1.7.5) dependency

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these three lines to your `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.headers=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=WARN
```